# How do I connect my ajax post to php and mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I spent hours testing all my code, step by step, and still can't make it work. I eventually got the php file to send a test object to the mysql database but I still can't get the jQuery ajax post to connect to php. Can anyone spot the issue? I get the "500 internal server error" message when I run the code.

Javascript:

```
    var jsonEntry = {"timestamp":"2015/01/21 22:18:00","note":"hi there","tags":["one", "two"]};

    // send json converted object to php file via ajax
    $("#sendButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: jsonEntry,
        error :
                function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(error);
                },
        success : 
                function(data) {
                        console.log('send success');
        }
        });
    });
```

PHP code from "ajax.php:"

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["data"])) {
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$timeStamp = $obj[timestamp]; //added semicolon here
$note = $obj[note];
$tags = $obj[tags];

//Connecting to a database
    //Connection info
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";

    //Code to connect
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

    // Select database to work with
    $selected = mysql_select_db("notes", $dbhandle)
        or die("Could not select examples");

    //Execute SQL query and return records
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO notes (dateAndTime, noteBody, noteTags) VALUES ('$timestamp', '$note', '$tags')");

    // Close the connection
    mysql_close($dbhandle);
}
?>
```

UPDATE:
I have added the semicolon where needed in the php file but now get error 200, "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF."

Comment: Add your ajax.php code here please.

Comment: if u get error 500 its always because there's a problem on the PHP side, in this case is the semicolon as Rob M says.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is a missing semicolon here:

```
$timeStamp = $obj[timestamp]
```

With this error fixed, you switch this line:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

to:

```
$json = $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: Thank you Rob! However, once I fixed that I ran into a "200" error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Close, but still have this:
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Connected"

Comment: try grabbing the JSON you are passing to the server and putting it through http://jsonlint.com/ to see where the error is